# Multiply each column in a data frame with the columns to its right in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large data frame with about 400.000 observations and 6.500 columns. I am looking for a **fast** way of multiplying each column with the columns to its right in turn.

An example data frame could look like this:

```
| V1  | V2  | V3  |  
----------------------
|  1  |  2  |  1  |
|  0  |  4  |  1  |
|  1  |  3  |  3  |
```

I would like to have something like this in the end:

```
| V1 | V2 | V3 | V1_V2 | V1_V3 | V2_V3 |
-----------------------------------------
|  1 |  2 |  1 |    2  |   1   |   2   |
|  0 |  4 |  1 |    0  |   0   |   4   |
|  1 |  3 |  3 |    3  |   0   |   9   |
```

I tried `itertools.combinations` but it is too slow. I am a beginner in Python, so maybe there is a simple solution I am not aware of.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If this is related to pandas you should add the proper tag.

Comment: No, if you want all 2 combinations I think your best bet is `itertools`

Answer (score 1):

The pandas vectorized operations (like multiplication) are efficient in themselves. You can use something like the following to take advantage of this:

```
# Extract column names
cols =  df.columns.tolist() 

# Generate all adjacent pairs, including the circular one
cols_to_create = [(cols[i], cols[i+1]) for i in range(len(cols)-1)] \
                 + [(cols[len(cols)-1], cols[0])] 

# Perform multiplication on all pairs
for x, y in cols_to_create:
    df[x+'_'+y] = df[x]*df[y]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work with itertools:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from  itertools import combinations
from io import StringIO

data = """
v1 v2 v3
1 2 1
0 4 1
1 3 3
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

l = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
df_add = pd.concat([df[col[1]] * (df[col[0]]) for col in l], axis=1, keys=l)
df_add.columns = df_add.columns.map(''.join)

df_add

   v1v2  v1v3  v2v3
0     2     1     2
1     0     0     4
2     3     3     9

df.join(df_add)

   v1  v2  v3  v1v2  v1v3  v2v3
0   1   2   1     2     1     2
1   0   4   1     0     0     4
2   1   3   3     3     3     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [Enhancing Performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) on pandas docs you can try the [df.eval() expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#eval-examples)

For example, `df.eval('0_V2 = V0 * V2', inplace=True)`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rows = 10000
cols = 300
df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in range(cols):
    df['V{}'.format(c)] = np.random.randn(rows)

n = len(df.columns)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        a = df.columns[i]
        b = df.columns[j]
        expr = '{0}_{1} = {0} * {1}'.format(a, b)
        df.eval(expr, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop is possible, but not strictly necessary. You can use [`pd.DataFrame.multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) to multiply a dataframe by a series *by index* and thus use a single loop:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'V1': [1, 0, 1],
                   'V2': [2, 4, 3],
                   'V3': [1, 1, 3]})

combs = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, idx+1:].multiply(df.iloc[:, idx], axis='index')\
                     .add_prefix(f'{df.columns[idx]}_') \
                   for idx in range(df.shape[1])], axis=1)

df = df.join(combs)

print(df)

   V1  V2  V3  V1_V2  V1_V3  V2_V3
0   1   2   1      2      1      2
1   0   4   1      0      0      4
2   1   3   3      3      3      9
```